# Does WinRT always bind to CollectionView like WPF?

Tags: windows-runtime, collectionview

When you bind to a collection in WPF it actually always binds to a CollectionView that is itself connected to the actual collection. For example, if you bind an ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection it will actually bind to a CollectionView that itself points at the specified ObservableCollection.

Does WinRT do the same thing/similar thing or does it bind directly to specified collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is no, it does not happen automatically. But you can still get a CollectionView for your ObservableCollection and then find that against the ItemsSource. So can extra step is required.

Comment: Phil, I can't see where you can get a CollectionView from an ObsCol in WinRT.  Did you find a way to get this?

Comment: You need to use the static method CollectionView.DefaultView